# Button Wont disable IOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uibutton

I'm coding a button that shoots a projectile when it is pressed. However, I
m trying to disable this button until I want it to be used. This is my code, it doesn't work:

```
#import "GameViewController.h"

@interface GameViewController ()

@end

@implementation GameViewController

//What happens when shoot button is pressed

-(IBAction)Shoot:(id)sender{

    Shoot.enabled = NO;

    //Step 1: upload image Step 2: Load image into image view Step 3: set coordinates and size
    UIImage * Bulletimage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"bullet.png"];
    UIImageView * Bullet = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:Bulletimage];
    [Bullet setFrame:CGRectMake(130,430,35,35)];
    [self.view addSubview:Bullet];

    //Creating Animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{ [Bullet setFrame:
                                                                                                              CGRectMake (130, 20, 35, 35)];}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {Bullet.hidden = YES;}];

}


//what happens when ready button is pressed
-(IBAction)Ready:(id)sender{

    //button disapears
    Ready.hidden = YES;

}

-(IBAction)Ready2:(id)sender{

    //button disapears
    Ready2.hidden = YES;

    if (Ready.hidden= YES, Ready2.hidden = YES)
    {
        //declaring images for animation
        Countdown.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                     nil];

        [Countdown setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
        Countdown.AnimationDuration = 3;
        [Countdown startAnimating];

       //end of loop
         }

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Is the animation occuring?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? There is literally no information in that phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `Shoot.enabled = NO;` into your `-()viewDidLoad` function. Right now you're not telling the button to be disabled until after the button has already been pressed.

Also, you should get into the habit of not capitalizing the first letter of the first word in variable and function names in objective-c, for example you might name a string `myString` or a function  `-(void)buttonPressed`. You generally only capitalize the first word of class names like `MyCustomObject`.

Comment: I put the Shoot.enabled = NO; into the view did load but now I'm having trouble overriding that with an if statement in the Shoot method.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm assuming you have your shoot method linked to your shoot button? If that's the case you won't be able to re enable it from that method. Possibly add `Shoot.enabled = YES;` to the end one of your Ready methods so that the button will be enabled after your app has gone through those methods.